# Spark Standalone cluster with python is not working

Tags: python, java, apache-spark

We have setup a Spark Standalone cluster with 1 Master node and 4 Worker Nodes.
When we submit the Spark command, we can see Application is running and getting distributed to worker nodes by master. But getting following exception every time.

**Exception**

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j2-defaults.properties
23/10/07 20:51:36 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 1959044@{{xxx}}
23/10/07 20:51:36 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for TERM
23/10/07 20:51:36 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for HUP
23/10/07 20:51:36 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for INT
23/10/07 20:51:36 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/10/07 20:51:36 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
23/10/07 20:51:36 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
23/10/07 20:51:36 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
23/10/07 20:51:36 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
23/10/07 20:51:36 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: root; groups with view permissions: EMPTY; users with modify permissions: root; groups with modify permissions: EMPTY
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:428)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkThreadUtils$.awaitResult(SparkThreadUtils.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$9(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:448)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcVI$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcVI$sp.java:23)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:985)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:158)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:984)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$7(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to 4103b8ddce96:36101
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:214)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:226)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 4103b8ddce96
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1533)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1307)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1257)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:156)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:153)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:153)
    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:41)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31)
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:106)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:220)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:46)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:189)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:175)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:990)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:516)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:429)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:486)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
```

**Spark Submit Command**

```
spark-submit --master spark://{master-node-addess}:7078 --files ./config.json  --jars ./jars/mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre8.jar,./jars/vertica-jdbc-12.0.4-0.jar --py-files ./Packages.zip job_build.py
```

When I run the same setup with single machine it is working fine. But when we tries to run this on standalone cluster it is failing.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like your nodes cannot reach out to each other. Can you check connectivity b/w the nodes? Also, are you using containers?

Comment: Found the issue.  
As explained in the above comment, worker nodes were unable to communicate to the master node. Because I was using docker container to run spark-submit to spark standalone cluster. When I run the spark-submit command from master node, things are started working fine.

Comment: Adding all the containers to a docker network should allow you to submit from worker nodes as well